# Asymptote - Using the olympiad package

Tags: pdftex, asymptote

I've been trying to use the Olympiad package for Asymptote on my Mac to use in TexShop (I'm working with pdfTeX). I just tried to put `import olympiad;` in front of my code, but it gives an error:

```
Processing file
error: could not load module 'olympiad'
```

On the following link's post, it says I have to install the olympiad package somehow? I'm fairly new to Asymptote in TeXShop, so I don't know how I should install/download/set up the package.

[Installing the olympiad package on Mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271369/installing-the-olympiad-package-on-mac)

How do I use the package? All I want to do is use the `add(pathticks());` method, although I suppose if I can't figure it out I can try doing it by hand.

Thanks in advance! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from the answer that you have linked? Specifically: create the directory `.asy/` in your home folder if it does not exist, download the package, and copy the file `olympiad.asy` into the `.asy/` folder.

Comment: At https://math.berkeley.edu/~monks/images/olympiad.asy.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I put the `olypmiad.asy` file? I didn't really understand the directions on the linked post. Am I supposed to create a .asy/ or ~asy/ folder? And where do I put it? In Library or in Users/name/ somewhere? I'm sorry, I've just been having a lot of trouble with my Asymptote and don't want to mess everything up.

Comment: You only need to say `export ASYMPTOTE_DIR=<the directory where you put it>`. Of course, you may want add this line to your `/.profile` file that is (should be) in your home directory. BTW, if you want to notify a certain user with the comment, you need to add their user name with an `@` in front.

Comment: @Marjin: I searched `ls -a ~/.asy` at the terminal, as suggested in the link. It returned `. ..` I think that means it does exist somewhere, but I don't know how to access and unhide it.

Comment: You probably want `ls -a ~/.asy`. On my Mac this has only a history directory. Nonetheless the above comment works. "say" means in this context: type on your terminal, i.e. where you "say" `ls -a /.asy`. (BTW, you can only ping one user, and there should not be a space between `@` and the user name.)

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat: Oh yeah, sorry. That's what I meant. But thank you so much! Using your and Marjin's help, I was able to solve the problem! I moved `olympiad.asy` into the `~/.asy` directory through terminal, and my code worked!

Comment: Good that you have solved the problem. I have voted to close this question as a duplicate of the earlier question.